# Search in new Sitecore ContentSearch using whole words

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

I am using new Sitecore search, and the issue I ran into is having results come for words that have nothing to do with my search term.

For example, searching for "lies" will find "applies". And this is not what I am looking for.

This is an example of search I am doing (simplified). It is a direct LINQ check for "Contains" on the "Content" property of the SearchResultItem, and most likely not what I supposed to do. It is just happen to be that samples I find online are practically doing so.

Example of my code (simplified). In here I break down the search sentence to separate keywords. By the way, I am looking for a way to show full sentence match first.

```
        using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Filter(i => i.Path.StartsWith(Home.Paths.FullPath))
                .Filter(GetTermPredicate(Term));

           // use results here
        }



    protected Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> GetTermPredicate(string term)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
        foreach (var tempTerm in term.Split(' '))
        {
            predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Content.Contains(tempTerm));
        }
        return predicate;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right. I got help from Sitecore Support.

In my version of Sitecore I can use the following to acheive search for a **whole** word instead of partial:

instead of:

> predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Content.**Contains**(tempTerm));

use

> predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Content.**Equals**(tempTerm));

Issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

Replace Filter in your code by Where, it should be fine, 
here is an example :

```
    var currentIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index"); 
using (var context = currentIndex.CreateSearchContext()) 
{ 
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(); 
  foreach (var currentWord in term.Split(‘ ‘)) 
  { 
      predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Content.Contains(currentWord )); 
  } 
  var results = context.GetQueryable().Where(predicate).GetResults(); 
}
```

Comment: Is "where" more superior than "filter"? I do use a bunch of facets, and the code excerpt above is the minimal code I give here to show my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Ahmed notes, you should use **Where** instead of **Filter**, since Filter has no effect on search rank.  The classic use case for filters is to apply a facet chosen by the user without distorting the ordering of results, as would happen if you used a Where clause.

> Filtering is similar to using Where to restrict the result list. Both methods will affect the result in the same 
>   result list, but when you use a Filter the scoring/ranking of the search hits is not affected by the filters. 
>   [Developer's Guide to Item Buckets and Search](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/developer%27s_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc7-usletter.pdf)

There's a good dicussion of when to use Filter on the Sitecore 7 team blog:
[Making Good Part 4: Filters, Paging and I'm feeling lucky.](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/07/Sitecore-7-Making-Google-Part-4.aspx)

Comment: Is "where" more superior than "filter"? I do use a bunch of facets, and the code excerpt above is just the minimal code I give here to show my issue. I **do** want to preserve the "better" results to be listed first. My **main objective** here is to NOT get as part of the result words such as "applies", "relies", etc. when I am searching for a word "lies".

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to search for whole words, you could prefix and postfix the searchterm with a space. Allthough this doesn't catch all situations.

Comment: I would prefer for cleaner solution if possible. Thank you though :)